# Compare input fields of dates of just mm/yy

Tags: php, laravel, date, datetime, php-carbon

I have two input fields where users can enter a date requested as mm/yy.  One field is from and the other is to.  On the backend I want to be able to convert those fields so I can do date comparisons.  I know if I put in some very strict rules so I 100% of the time get it in that exact format I can use Date or strtotime and get what I need.  I would rather have looser rules in place as some may enter mm-yy, mm-yyyy, mm/yyyy, m/yy, etc.

My question is there any way to convert if it potentially comes in a variety of formats as I know users don't always follow the recommended format.  I am doing this in a laravel app so maybe Carbon has some way of doing it as well.

Thanks

Comment: `users don't always follow the recommended format` why not provide a datepicker to safeguard the input and ease of access

Comment: Laravel type casting for date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Carbon supports all the date formats that PHP [supports](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php). So any of the formats listed under "Localized Notations" can be used to create a valid date. For example:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
$date = new Carbon('2008-6');
$date = new Carbon('2008-06');
$date = new Carbon('June 2008');
$date = new Carbon('2008 June');
```

If you want to support any other formats, you could use the `Carbon::createFromFormat` method to create a date from a given format. You could create a new class to support multiple new formats, for example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use InvalidArgumentException;

class MonthYearParser
{
    const SUPPORTED_FORMATS = [
        'm-y',
        'm-Y',
        'm/y',
        'm/Y',
    ];

    public static function convertYearMonthToDate(string $input)
    {
        foreach(self::SUPPORTED_FORMATS as $format) {
            try {
                $date = Carbon::createFromFormat($format, $input);
                return $date;
            } catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {
            }
        }
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("Input is not in a valid year-month format");
    }

}
```

You can then use this class in, for example, a [custom validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#custom-validation-rules) or in a controller as:

```
MonthYearParser::convertYearMonthToDate('6/2008')
```